Why does glm in R with family binomial(link="log") sometimes require start values?
While simulating some studies and analyzing them in R with glm(…, family=binomial) and binary and continuous covariates the function sometimes complains:

no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values

This only happens with link="log" but not with link="logit". (The choice of the link function is not mine; I need to simulate relative risks.) In this particular example I can use the model ae ~ TRT + AGE but not ae ~ TRT * AGE:
> dput(d)
structure(list(TRT = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("placebo", 
"verum"), class = "factor"), AGE = c(39.7487662482072, 50.1799716204745, 
33.3045815905937, 38.0315677387993, 48.5841412266105, 47.2349106894153, 
38.1600311512517, 27.738632829439, 43.6232076313004, 37.3394328366416, 
37.590035880194, 36.0186173490767, 54.2502475692696, 45.5122737460622, 
30.6935441725765, 44.2362429427211, 30.229949563021, 41.554016200862, 
48.3781816616456, 42.7388087687717, 41.3662137160875, 44.044378841722, 
34.1693526744936, 40.3652575218051, 32.6305917972471, 59.6961875303972, 
14.972782257658, 51.1042166486761, 32.6220522256254, 34.1277732393448, 
32.5147509852927, 43.5272141962345, 22.4337643342435, 46.7163458805283, 
58.7961685435884, 39.4696740660955, 45.2631826365689, 28.6236265146614, 
39.1053872190327, 38.4418306901041, 38.9154609346267, 49.3065159458693, 
49.8854291946365, 42.743416440472, 36.593435912556, 50.3094002474162, 
25.2467062247769, 25.9631953495408, 50.183216552195, 43.1630235325955, 
39.484028020715, 30.760758073483, 44.1099004897372, 53.0787176407533, 
28.8868124792957, 23.8002913513491, 36.8486854897447, 35.7992086333115, 
36.8217592746943, 46.4797492054728, 39.3439003225626, 38.9853144287762, 
48.6407924104783, 48.4570777980696, 24.1018033132868, 47.9806140420494, 
32.831890637965, 37.3030109318783, 32.347169370539, 34.3527037438039, 
31.1037953243259, 25.167342712201, 45.6195833859188, 24.9319176156433, 
57.7858917718018, 48.3952531818224, 57.6041557474735, 37.5874128252175, 
40.2161861439315, 46.5485174118935, 41.4776267604738, 36.1551131739081, 
50.2126132793173, 43.1623681906198, 24.7898982814906, 36.0263371058247, 
37.5345572690356, 39.435597693454, 22.9833444605649, 27.2064057871258, 
30.2699080938295, 53.6779893571545, 19.5873248933428, 28.2510703807555, 
31.1065131489478, 19.1338294814643, 53.2483634625907, 46.2987786295095, 
31.8461326828004, 44.8690561376469), ae = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
> glm(ae~TRT+AGE,data=d, family=binomial(link="log"))

Call:  glm(formula = ae ~ TRT + AGE, family = binomial(link = "log"), 
    data = d)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     TRTverum          AGE  
  -1.176887     0.176749     0.008414  

Degrees of Freedom: 99 Total (i.e. Null);  97 Residual
Null Deviance:      138.3 
Residual Deviance: 137.3        AIC: 143.3
> glm(ae~TRT*AGE,data=d, family=binomial(link="log"))
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values

How am I supposed to know what starting values to provide? And if there is an algorithm for finding them for a particular data set why doesn't the function glm use that itself? I am pretty sure that when using SAS I was able to get a result with one those “non-working” data sets. Regrettably, I don't have access to SAS any more.
Interestingly, with this data set
> set.seed(310);
> d=data.frame(TRT=gl(2,50,labels=c("placebo","verum")),AGE=rnorm(100,40,10),ae=rbinom(100,1,0.5))
> glm(ae~TRT*AGE,data=d, family=binomial(link="log"))

Call:  glm(formula = ae ~ TRT * AGE, family = binomial(link = "log"), 
    data = d)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)      TRTverum           AGE  TRTverum:AGE  
     0.24568      -0.62229      -0.02189       0.01588  

Degrees of Freedom: 99 Total (i.e. Null);  96 Residual
Null Deviance:      137.6 
Residual Deviance: 134.3        AIC: 142.3


I get a result without providing starting values.

I think the logbin package does what you're looking for. If I'm not mistaken, these models are known in the literature as log-binomial models.

@COOLSerdash Thanks for the tip but: > logbin(ae~TRT*AGE,data=d) Error in logbin(ae ~ TRT * AGE, data = d) : models with interactions are not supported by logbin

You could just generate the interaction term yourself and add this to the formula. Other packages are lbm or lbreg. Both work with your example.

The problem is not just in the starting values, but rather that a log link does not ensure that the linear predictor stays within the domain that produces valid responses.
The canonical logit link guarantees that $\mu=g^{-1}(\eta)=1/(1+e^{-\eta})$ is within $(0,\,1)$, i.e. a valid probability, for any $\eta$ within $(-\infty,\infty)$. Discounting finite numerical precision, the fact that a prediction of exactly $0$ or $1$ is not possible is of very little practical relevance, but it is important, as we'll see.
With the log link you can easily get $g^{-1}(\eta)=e^\eta$ to produce $\mu\ge1$ for $\eta\ge0$.
This becomes a problem rather quickly when you try to calculate the link $\text{log}\big(\mu/(1-\mu)\big)$ (division by zero or log of non-positive number) or the variance $\mu\times(1-\mu)$ (can go negative). If this happens at any point during the fitting process it is unlikely to still converge, although perhaps a boundary termination after step halving might save you.
The error that R gives you is because their default initialization values produce $\eta\ge0$ at the first Fisher scoring iteration (for observation 27 to be exact), so it's not possible to calculate the deviance or do a step halving as there was no previous step. You can provide negative starting values to brute-force past the first iteration, but there's no guarantee that the algorithm won't get stuck in the next one, or the one after that. You'd just get a different error.
Now, I did not quite expect this, but SAS is smarter about this. Your first problematic model converges in PROC GENMOD with no manual specification whatsoever, and this solution can also be replicated in R using sufficiently close starting values:
proc genmod data=d;
   class trt(ref="placebo");
   model ae(event="1") = trt|age / dist=bin link=log;
quit;

Parameter               Estimate 
Intercept                -0.3684 
TRT          verum       -1.2666 
AGE                      -0.0115 
AGE*TRT      verum        0.0356 

Unfortunately, the internals of this procedure are proprietary (they mention "a ridge-stabilized Newton-Raphson algorithm") and I can't find any more hints in the documentation, so I'm left guessing as to how you might approach this more cleverly.
Addendum
As mentioned in the comments providing starting values can also be done in the mean scale, which for particular choices can get this model to converge in R. Most likely the proprietary softwares (including Stata, which also converges more readily) differ mainly in how they determine those starting values $\mu_0$ for the first Fisher scoring iteration.
After a bit more consideration I realize there is another straightforward and quite reliable way to find starting coefficients for such log-binomial models: fit them using a log-linked Poisson GLM first. That will also get you convergence for this model in R:
f1 <- glm(ae~TRT*AGE, data=d, family=poisson("log"))
f2 <- glm(ae~TRT*AGE, data=d, family=binomial("log"), start=coef(f1))
#> (Intercept)      TRTverum           AGE  TRTverum:AGE  
#>    -0.36867      -1.26630      -0.01146       0.03557

A log-Poisson GLM does not guarantee valid probability predictions in the form of $\eta < 0$ because its domain will happily support $\mu \ge 1$, a further tweak that is sometimes recommended in literature is to make the intercept more negative (and ensure it is negative in the first place) should its coefficients still result in non-convergence for the binomial case.
There are third-party R packages that attempt to solve exactly this problem, by no means exhaustive:

logbin by default fits a constrained Expectation-Maximization algorithm, which claims to always converge to the MLE. A key trade-off seems to be that it uses a somewhat complicated latent reparametrization internally, so computations either scale exponentially with the number of parameters or require a specific kind of overparametrization that doesn't allow for interactions out of the box.
risks implements many approaches and can even step through them to find what works; options include the Poisson hot-start, a wrapper for logbin's EM, and marginal standardization (contributed by this package specifically). It also targets the same problem for the identity link/risk differences, which is even more numerically unstable because now you need $0\lt\eta\lt 1$.
lbreg and lbm were also mentioned, at least the former seems to implement a constrained optimization via stats::constrOptim that can also be performed by logbin above.


Thanks for your comments. I was aware of the domain problem (which is why we used the canonical link so far in our simulations, but now we needed RR so we gave link="log" a try) but as SAS is capable of calculating that example without help (thanks for taking the effort to try it!) I thought there should be a way for glm to do so, too.

+1 It is worth mentioning that glm.fit by default, instead of trying to initialize the parameter vector $\boldsymbol\beta$, initializes $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ to mustart <- (n * y + 0.5)/(n + 1).  This sometimes work but sometimes doesn't.  In the above case a remedy seems to be to instead use e.g. something simple like mustart=rep(.5, nrow(d)) as an additional argument in the call to glm.

FWIW, Stata finds a solution with this dataset and log link without fuss or special action. It's perhaps of interest that predicted means vary from about 0.35 to about 0.6, so nowhere near the limits of 0 and 1; and that logit, log and for that matter identity links all produce very similar predicted values,

@NickCox Is that Stata procedure also proprietary? If not, maybe R's glm can learn from it

Stata's ado code is visible by any user; its  C code and some code is compiled and as you say proprietary. It would take me too much rummaging around to say whether the most important bit of code is one or the other. So, the shortest practical answer: That bit of the code may well be proprietary.

@diffset I just recalled a strategy that can more reliably get you reasonably close to the log-binomial fit, see my edit. It's important to keep in mind however that the numerical instability is intrinsic to the non-canonical link for the reasons mentioned, so without actual parameter constraints (which are not implemented in any of the options discussed here) there's no guarantee that any Newton-Raphson algorithm converges. Another comment mentioned logbin which uses a constrained EM approach, but it needs a significant internal (over)reparametrization which has its own drawbacks.

@PBulls The strategy you describe is an improvement of the current situation. Although it might not always work it allows more data sets to be analyzed. So I am wondering if this strategy shouldn't be implemented directly into glm(.fit) as I also mentioned in the question. So instead of bailing out with the error message and asking the user to provide starting values it could try harder to find them on its own. What do you think should this be brought to the attention of  the R developers?

I am no core R developer so can only opine, but I wouldn't go there for several reasons. 1) it's easy to implement by hand in user space. 2) glm is a workhorse for any IRLS you give it (custom families too), so it would be very difficult to unequivocally determine internally what the user wants exactly. #1 is much more transparent. 3) it introduces non-zero and (for other GLMs) often unnecessary overhead -- not good if you're fitting thousands of them. No other software package does this out of the box either. Also, have a look at risks which does this (and more) for you.

It's surprisingly tricky to write a starting-value routine that works when the distribution and link are specified separately and can be arbitrary. (yes, I've tried).  It's fairly easy to do it for any specific link and variance function (for binomial(log) use c(-1,0,0,0,0,...,0)

The answer is superb.  In addition, it is very strange to use a log link and have to deal with so many interactions that are required to keep probabilities legal.  Just model log odds and use that model to compute any covariate-specific risk ratio of interest.

Pbulls answer explains the problem well. The values cannot be outside 0 and 1, which the logit link satisfies for every possible starting condition but the log link doesn't.
There is a hack to get around this without the need to search for start values. That is by simply removing the limits on $y$. The likelihood function becomes a different distribution and it can go wrong (you end up with values $y > 1$, but this may only be the case with weird situations).
### create a copy of the family object
fam = binomial(link = "log")

### remove the requirement mu < 1 by redefining it
### now it is only (mu > 0)
### instead of (mu > 0 & mu < 1)
fam$validmu = function(mu) {
    all(is.finite(mu)) && all(mu > 0)
}

### make sure that we don't get negative variance
fam$variance = function(mu) {
    v = mu*(1-mu)
    v[v <= 0] = 10^-30
    v
}

### prevent overflow of dev.residuals
fam$dev.resids = function (y, mu, wt) {
   mu[mu >= 1] = 0.99
   resid = ifelse(y == 1, log(y/mu), log((1-y)/(1-mu)) )
   2*wt*resid
}

### now the model does compute
mod = glm(ae~TRT*AGE,data=d, family=fam)

### verify if the values get between 0 and 1
### the result is zero so it worked
sum(predict(mod, type ="response") > 1)


This might afterall not be the easiest response. I thought that one could just play around with the variance and the validmu, but the computation of the deviance residuals is also influenced.
